# web2py insert with variable table and field name e.g. with dict

Tags: python, web2py

Is there a way to handle table name and field name at run time ?

I have found references to an insert method that takes a dict as argument
But assuming rd is a dict with 10 entries, key = name of the field, value = value to be inserted, the following code will fail

```
    db.OrdersFull.insert(rd)
```

With error :TypeError: insert() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
1)any clue?
2)with this solution, the table name (OrdersFull) must still be known at development time, any way to insert into a table whose name is known at run time only ?
3)Is there a place where one can found reference information for available web2py API calls ?

Answer (score 1):

To access a table based on a Python expression that yields its name, you can do:

```
tablename = 'mytable'
db[tablename]
```

This is documented [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Run-time-field-and-table-modification).

To use a dictionary with the `.insert()` method, you can use standard Python keyword argument unpacking:

```
db[tablename].insert(**mydict)
```

That is not specific to web2py or the DAL but is standard Python syntax.

There is also a special method you can use to filter out any items from the dictionary that are not fields in the table:

```
db.mytable.insert(**db.mytable._filter_fields(mydict))
```

The above is useful if you are passing in a record that was previously selected from the table, as it will automatically filter out the `id` field from the record (you do not want to specify an `id` on insert, as one will be created automatically by the database).

Regarding API reference, aside from the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29), there is also [this API documentation](https://web2py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony, that is very helpfull